# Apache Spark - How does internal job scheduler in spark define what are users and what are pools

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, job-scheduling

I am sorry about being a little general here, but I am a little confused about how job scheduling works internally in spark. From the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) I get that it is some sort of implementation of Hadoop Fair Scheduler.

I am unable to come around to understand that who exactly are users here (are the linux users, hadoop users, spark clients?). I am also unable to understand how are the pools defined here. For example, In my hadoop cluster I have given resource allocation to two different pools (lets call them team 1 and team 2). But in spark cluster, wont different pools and the users in them instantiate their own spark context? Which again brings me to question that what parameters do I pass when I am setting property to spark.scheduler.pool.

I have a basic understanding of how driver instantiates a spark context and then splits them into task and jobs. May be I am missing the point completely here but I would really like to understand how Spark's internal scheduler works in context of actions, tasks and job

Answer (score 6):

I find official [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) quite thorough and covering all your questions. However, one might find it hard to digest from the first time.

Let us put some definitions and rough analogues before we delve into details. `application` is what creates SparkContext `sc` and may be referred to as something you deploy with *spark-submit*. `job` is an action in spark definition of *transformation and action* meaning anything like *count*, *collect* etc.

There are two main and in some sense separate topics: Scheduling Across `application`s and Scheduling Within `application`. The former relates more to Resource Managers including Spark Standalone FIFO only mode and also concept of *static* and *dynamic* allocation.

The later, Scheduling Within Spark `application` is the matter of your question, as I understood from your comment. Let me try to describe what happens there at some level of abstraction.

Suppose, you submitted your `application` and you have two `job`s

```
sc.textFile("..").count()   //job1
sc.textFile("..").collect() //job2
```

If this code happens to be executed in the same thread there is no much interesting happening here, *job2* and all its *tasks* get resources *only after* *job1* is done.

Now say you have the following

```
thread1 { job1 }
thread2 { job2 }
```

This is getting interesting. By default, within your `application` scheduler will use *FIFO* to allocate resources to all the tasks of whichever `job` happens to appear to scheduler as first. Tasks for the other `job` will get resources only when there are spare cores and no more pending tasks from more "prioritized" first `job`.

Now suppose you set `spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR` for your `application`. From now on each `job` has a notion of `pool` it belongs to. If you do nothing then for every job `pool` label is "default". To set the label for your `job` you can do the following

```
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool1").textFile("").count() // job1
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool2").textFile("").collect() // job2
```

One important note here is that [setLocalProperty](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@setLocalProperty(key:String,value:String):Unit) is effective per thread and also all spawned threads. What it means for us? Well if you are within the same thread it means nothing as `job`s are executed one after another.
However, once you have the following

```
thread1 { job1 } // pool1
thread2 { job2 } // pool2
```

*job1* and *job2* become unrelated in the sense of resource allocation. In general, properly configuring each *pool* in fairscheduler [file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/job-scheduling.html#configuring-pool-properties) with *minShare > 0* you can be sure that `job`s from different pools will have resources to proceed.

However, you can go even further. By default, within each `pool` `job`s are queued up in a *FIFO* manner and this situation is basically the same as in the scenario when we have had FIFO mode and `job`s from different threads. To change that you you need to change the `pool` in the xml file to have `<schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>`.

Given all that, if you just set `spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR` and let all the `job`s fall into the same "default" pool, this is roughly the same as if you would use default `spark.scheduler.mode=FIFO` and have your `job`s be launched in different threads. If you still just want single "default" *fair* pool just change config for "default" pool in xml file to reflect that.

To leverage the mechanism of `pool`s you need to define the concept of `user` which is the same as setting "spark.scheduler.pool" from a proper thread to a proper value. For example, if your `application` listens to JMS, then a message processor may set the pool label for each message processing `job` depending on its content.

Eventually, not sure if the number of words is less than in the official doc, but hopefully it helps is some way :)

Comment: Thanks for this! Is it possible to load the XML file if it's in the resource folder? (Here's more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130052/spark-session-builder-cannot-find-resource-file)

Answer (score 4):

By default spark works with FIFO scheduler where jobs are executed in FIFO manner.

But if you have your cluster on YARN, YARN has pluggable scheduler, it means in YARN you can scheduler of your choice. If  you are using YARN distributed by CDH you will have FAIR scheduler by deafult but you can also go for Capacity scheduler.

If you are using YARN distributed by HDP you will have CAPACITY scheduler by default and you can move to FAIR if you need that.

How Scheduler works with spark?

I'm assuming that you have your spark cluster on YARN.

When you submit a job in spark, it first hits your resource manager. Now your resource manager is responsible for all the scheduling and allocating resources. So its basically same as that of submitting a job in Hadoop.

How scheduler works?

**Fair scheduling** is a method of assigning resources to jobs such that all jobs get, on average, an equal share of resources over time. When there is a single job running, that job uses the entire cluster. When other jobs are submitted, tasks slots that free up are assigned to the new jobs, so that each job gets roughly the same amount of CPU time(using preemption killing all over used tasks). Unlike the default Hadoop scheduler(FIFO), which forms a queue of jobs, this lets short jobs finish in reasonable time while not starving long jobs. It is also a reasonable way to share a cluster between a number of users. Finally, fair sharing can also work with job priorities - the priorities are used as weights to determine the fraction of total compute time that each job should get.

The **CapacityScheduler** is designed to allow sharing a large cluster while giving each organization a minimum capacity guarantee. The central idea is that the available resources in the Hadoop Map-Reduce cluster are partitioned among multiple organizations who collectively fund the cluster based on computing needs. There is an added benefit that an organization can access any excess capacity no being used by others. This provides elasticity for the organizations in a cost-effective manner.

Comment: I understand how scheduler works on resource managers like YARN and mesos. I guess my question relates to how spark's internal scheduler works. I am trying to understand how 'tasks' are allotted JVM resources after spark context is initiated and spark driver submits them to different executors. The documentation given is quite ambiguous on that and I am unable to understand what is the concept of fair sharing when it comes to different tasks within a job

Answer (score 1):

Spark internally uses FIFO/FCFS job scheduler. But, when you talk about the tasks, it works in a Round Robin fashion. It will be clear if we concentrate on the below example:

Suppose, the first job in Spark's own queue doesn't require all the resources of the cluster to be utilized; so, immediately second job in the queue will also start getting executed. Now, both jobs are running simultaneously. Each job has few tasks to be executed in order to execute the whole job. Assume, the first job assigns 10 tasks and the second one assigns 8. Then, those 18 tasks will share the CPU cycles of the whole cluster in a preemptive manner. If you want to further drill down, lets start with executors.

There will be few executors in the cluster. Assume the number is 6. So, in an ideal condition, each executor will be assigned 3 tasks and those 3 tasks will get same CPU time of the executors(separate JVM).

This is how spark internally schedules the tasks.