# Is FAIR available for Spark Standalone cluster mode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-standalone

I'm having 2 node cluster with *spark standalone* cluster manager. I'm triggering more than one job using same `sc` with Scala multi threading.What I found is my jobs are scheduled one after another because of **FIFO** nature so I tried to use **FAIR** scheduling

```
    conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
    conf.set("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", sys.env("SPARK_HOME") + "/conf/fairscheduler.xml")

    val job1 = Future {
    val job = new Job1()
    job.run()
    }

    val job2 =Future {
    val job = new Job2()
    job.run()
    }


    class Job1{
        def run()
            sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "mypool1")
        }
        }

    class Job2{
        def run()
            sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "mypool2")
        }
        }



 <pool name="mypool1">
 <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
 <weight>1</weight>
 <minShare>2</minShare>    
  </pool>

 <pool name="mypool2">
 <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
 <weight>1</weight>
 <minShare>2</minShare>    
  </pool>
```

***Job1 and Job2 will be triggered from an launcher class***. Even after setting these properties, my jobs are handled in **FIFO**. 
Is **FAIR** available for Spark Standalone cluster mode?Is there a page
where it's described in more details? I can't seem to find much about
FAIR and Standalone in Job Scheduling.I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226769/how-to-enable-fair-scheduler-in-spark) SOF question.am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think standalone is the problem. You described creating only one pool, so I think your problem is that you need at least one more pool and assign each job to a different pool.

FAIR scheduling is done across pools, anything within the same pool will run in FIFO mode anyway.

This is based on the documentation here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#default-behavior-of-pools

Comment: can you pls give me some example on how to "assign each job to a different pool." ?

Comment: I just updated my question. can you pls look into it ?

Comment: Still my jobs are running in sequence. can you help me here ?