# Spark Session Builder Cannot Find Resource File

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

For context, I'm trying to configure my Spark session to use fair scheduling. For that reason I have a file, fairscheduler.xml, at the 'root' of my `resources` folder. This file is correctly packaging into my build folder in the location I'd expect.

To further prove that's working, I have this line:

```
val mypath = getClass.getResource("/fairscheduler.xml")
```

That is working and returns exactly the path I'd expect: `/<some path>/<my jar>/fairscheduler.xml`

The following is throwing a FileNotFound exception:

```
sessionBuilder
    ...
    .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
    .config("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", mypath.toString) <- THIS LINE
    .config("spark.scheduler.pool", "fair_pool")
    ...
    .getOrCreate
```

Just for sanity, I have logged out `mypath.toString`.

Why is it that the spark session builder can't recognize a resource file that otherwise seems valid? Does it expect "spark configuration" files to exist somewhere specific? Or am I completely missing some dumb little thing here?

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that resource files weren't necessarily in the file system. Writing a temp file seems to work :) Add that comment as an answer and I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Apache Spark limitation but an expected behaviour of how resource files are handled in Java JAR files. Question [How to get a path to a resource in a Java JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file) provides more details and a workaround of persisting the content in a temp file.